# IS this possible to do on SharePoint 2010 workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow

I’m currently working on the following list. The data that I’m working on is under ‘Tenanted’.

This is a live list and is updated daily by officers in another team called Housing Initiatives. This is a list of the properties they let out to our homeless household and my team will eventually need to visit these newly let properties.  Will it be possible for Sharepoint to create the following:

- An alert/workflow for each officer in my team to inform them that a new property has been let out?
- Put in certain trigger words before an alert or workflow is created?
- Override the alert/workflow if the officer is on annual leave?
- When an alert/workflow is created is it possible to extract certain data from the list and put it in a Excel spreadsheet as part of the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint Designer, you can send notifications to each officer in your team when a new property has been let out. However switching on certain trigger words makes you workflow a little more complex, and the advice is to move over to Visual Studio created Workflow instead of a SharePoint Designer one. That's also true for your third bullit.

Copy-pasting data to Excel is a different story though, especially when working with an older version of SharePoint. You have to use some kind of .NET 3rd party product unless you want to build a tool yourself. There are several 3rd party products out there, but I won't point you to a specific one. You'll find them on a simple search string in your favorite browser. However, using a 3rd party product will shorten your time to market since building one yourself takes time.

I advice you to start reading here: [Create SharePoint workflow solutions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/creating-sharepoint-workflow-solutions).

Answer (score 0):

For your all requirements, as 4rchit3ct suggested, you need to deploy a custom workflow solution in Visual Studio, OOB/Designer workflow cannot achieve your purpose.

Besides, for you first and third point, you can create a alert for your list and select "All changes" of the "Change Type" option. Then when new columns are created(Actually all the changes in this list), users will receive an email.

What's more, you can also edit the contents of the alert email. Refer to below articles about how to edit the alert template:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/anolan/2008/01/07/is-it-possible-to-modify-sharepoint-email-notifications/